# jQuery modal dialog validators initially displayed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, dialog

In a MVC 3 project I'm using a modal jQuery dialog to reset a password and I am using MVC's client site validators for validation.  Here is the code for my rest password partial view:

```
@model Company.Project.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.Users.ResetPasswordViewModel
@using Company.Project.Web.MVC;

@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPasswordPost", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ResetPasswordForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "editor-label-dialog" })
        </td>
        <td class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "text-box-dialog" })
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm, new { @class = "editor-label-dialog" })
        </td>
        <td class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm, new { @class = "text-box-dialog" })
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Here is my HTML and JavaScript:

```
<input id="ResetPasswordButton" type="submit" value="Reset Password" />       
<div id="ResetPasswordDialog" title="Reset Password" style="display: none"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ResetPasswordDialog").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
        width: 440,
        height: 240,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons:
        {
            "Submit": function () {
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#ResetPasswordForm"));

                if ($("#ResetPasswordForm").valid()) {
                    $.post("/Admin/Users/ResetPasswordPost", $("#ResetPasswordForm").serialize(), function () { $("#ResetPasswordDialog").dialog("close"); });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#ResetPasswordButton").click(function () {
        $("#ResetPasswordDialog").html("").load("/Admin/Users/ResetPassword", function () { $("#ResetPasswordDialog").dialog("open"); });
    });
});
```

This works fine except this line `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#ResetPasswordForm"));` causes the validators to display as soon as the form pops up and before the user has a chance to enter the passwords and submit.  Is it possible to not have the validators display until after the user has tried to submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere is your call to `$('#ResetPasswordForm').validate();`.  Wherever that is, move it to the `open` option of the dialog (because validate doesn't work on hidden forms very well by default).

Your submit button should not do what it does.  Instead just have it submit the form, and let the validate stuff take care of the rest.  You'll end up with something like this:

```
$("#ResetPasswordDialog").dialog(
        { //your options
        buttons: {
          "Submit": function() {$('#ResetPasswordForm').submit(); }
        },
        open: function(){
            var dialog = $(this);
            $("#ResetPasswordDialog").validate({
                 submitHandler:function(){
                    //do your post here then close the dialog with the below code
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                 }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

And that will go something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/xSNZ4/

Comment: Without this line $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#ResetPasswordForm")); I get the following error in jquery.validate.min.js:

Unable to get value of the property 'settings': object is null or undefined

If I add the line in the open function I get the exact same behavior where the validators are already displayed when the form is opened.

Comment: In that case, try a different plan, instead of calling `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` try calling `$.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement($('#ResetPasswordDialog input').get(0))` and so on for each element in the form.

Comment: I decided to give up on trying to use MVC data annotations for validation and went with jQuery validation which gives me the desired behavior.